# BigQuery: Intrigued by error message

Tags: google-bigquery

I encountered a very intriguing error message from BigQuery today. I was querying a table that has a field named `user.yob` (as in year of birth). I was being a bit sloppy when I wrote my query, projecting onto a non-existent field "user.age" instead of `user.yob`:

```
SELECT user.age, ...
```

This generated the following error message:

```
BigQuery error in mk operation: Field 'user.age' not found; did you mean 'user.yob'?
```

Now I'm very curious..

**How did BigQuery manage to suggest the precise field I actually meant to project on?**

By the way, the table I was querying has many many fields (around 50 at least), so it's not like `user.yob` was the only available field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BigQuery knows about all the fields in your table, and it runs variation of [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to find the ones which look closest to the names which were not found. If the distance is close enough, there is a chance that the field name was simply misspelled.

Comment: Thanks, you and BQ teams rocks!